# SelectRadio in HTML Table forces linebreak

Tags: visualforce, css, html

So I have a table, and I'm looking to have and inline SelectRadio.  The Issue is that it is being pushed to the next line.  I've tried a few things, but haven't been able to figure it out.  Any pointers?

See Pic:  I want the radio buttons to go to the right of "TD TEXT".  The radio buttons are instead put into the next line TD, with colspan 2.

[image]

```
    .threeColumnGrid > .cell{
        display: inline-block;
        width:33%;
        vertical-align: text-top;
        height:100%;
        }
    .left{
        text-align:left;
    }
    .right{
        text-align:right;
    }

<div class="cell" >
    <table >
           <tr>
              <td class="right"> TD TEXT: </td>
                 <td > 
                     <apex:selectRadio id="Radio" value="{!values}" >
                         <apex:selectOptions value="{!options}"/>
                     </apex:selectRadio>
                 </td>
             </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

Here is the inspect element.  I can see the issue, I just don't know enough to fix it.  Help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, so as I went along many, many wrong paths... the answer is: shove it all in a panel grid, inside the TR, and give it some columns.  Adjust the margins to move it for perfect alignment.

```
<tr>
      <apex:panelgrid columns="2" style="float:right;">
                  <apex:outputtext value="TEXT:"/>
                    <apex:selectRadio id="pmRadio" value="{!tempwrap.options}" style="margin-top:-8px;" >
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!Options}"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>

           <apex:outputtext value="TEXT:"/>
                    <apex:selectRadio id="ppRadio" value="{!tempwrap.options}" style="margin-top:-7px;" >
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!recOptions}"/>
                    </apex:selectRadio>
 </apex:panelgrid>
     </tr>
```

UPDATE:  So this doesn't work for apex:inputcheckbox... still throws it to another line, but works fine for selectRadio?  Anyway, I guess with playing around it can be made to work.

Comment: Perhaps you might get more consistent results if you also give them the style `display: inline-block`

Comment: I tried but it didn't really do anything - but I'll take your advice and start putting that into the CSS, so hopefully I don't run into any issues next time.  Thanks!